# How can I run "export" command inside a java Process on Android?

Tags: java, android, shell, processbuilder

I try to run shell scripts on Android using an application written in Java. I want to be able to run Android commands as root such as `am` or `pm` which need an `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib` command before. Unfortunately, the `export` command doesn't work. Here is the Java code I wrote :

```
private String readScript(String scriptPath) {

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        // Read the script line by line
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scriptPath));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        content.append("exit").append('\n');
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(UpdateService.LOG_NAME, "Impossible to read script : " + e.getMessage());

    }

    return content.toString();

}

public StringBuffer runScript(String scriptPath) {

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        // Start the shell process
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("su");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.directory(new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir));
        pb.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/system/lib");
        Process process = pb.start();

        // Execute the script
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
        os.write(readScript(scriptPath));
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // Get the output of the commands
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d(UpdateService.LOG_NAME, "Error while executing " + scriptPath + " : " + e.getMessage());

    }

    return output;

}
```

I simply call it like :

```
Shell = new Shell();
StringBuffer output = shell.runScript("script.sh");
```

The script I try to run :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib
printenv
am start -W -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$InputMethodAndLanguageSettingsActivity
```

Gives me the output :

```
_=/system/bin/printenv
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,32768
LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
ANDROID_DATA=/data
RANDOM=21985
ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=10
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, the environment variable set with the `environment()` method of `ProcessBuilder` seems to not be set and the `export` in the script doesn't work either.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks!

**Edit**

As suggested I also tried a version with `exec()` :

```
public StringBuffer runScript(String scriptPath) {

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        // Start the shell process
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        // Execute the script commands
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
        os.write(readScript(scriptPath));
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // Get the output of the command
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        in.close();

        process.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Log.d(UpdateService.LOG_NAME, "Error while executing " + scriptPath + ".");

    }

    return output;

}
```

This time I get the same output without `stderr` (Segmentation fault) :

```
_=/system/bin/printenv
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,32768
LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
ANDROID_DATA=/data
RANDOM=21985
ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=10
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

So export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib` still doesn't work. It seems to me that `ProcessBuilder` is a better way to launch process as it it dedicated to it. Is it right?

**Edit2**

`am` and `pm` are actually wrappers to launch a java executable. I tried to implement a C version of this wrapper to create a full environment that should work in any circumstance. Here is the content of am :

```
# Script to start "am" on the device, which has a very rudimentary
# shell.
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/am.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.am.Am "$@"
```

And this is my C version :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[], const char *envp[]) {
    const char **p;

    const int NUM_ARG = 3;
    const char *APP_PROCESS = "/system/bin/app_process";
    const char *BIN = "/system/bin";
    const char *AM = "com.android.commands.am.Am";

    const int NUM_ENV = 11;
    const char *ENV[] = {
        "PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/system/xbin/bb:/data/local/bin",
        "SHELL=/system/bin/sh",
        "MKSH=/system/bin/sh",
        "HOME=/data",
        "HOSTNAME=android",
        "USER=root",
        "LOGNAME=root",
        "TERM=xterm",
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib/",
        "CLASSPATH=/system/framework/am.jar",
        NULL
    };

    int i = 0;
    char *a[argc + NUM_ARG];
    a[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(APP_PROCESS) + 1);
    strcpy(a[i++], APP_PROCESS);
    a[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(BIN) + 1);
    strcpy(a[i++], BIN);
    a[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(AM) + 1);
    strcpy(a[i++], AM);
    p = argv + 1;
    for (; i < argc + NUM_ARG - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(*p) + 1);
        strcpy(a[i], *p++);
    }
    a[i] = (char *)malloc(1);
    a[i] = NULL;

    p = envp;
    int envc = 0;
    while (*p++ != NULL) envc++;

    char *v[envc + NUM_ENV];
    for (i = 0; i < envc; i++) {
        v[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(envp[i]) + 1);
        strcpy(v[i], envp[i]);
    }
    p = ENV;
    while (*p != NULL) {
        v[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(*p) + 1);
        strcpy(v[i++], *p++);
    }
    v[i] = (char *)malloc(1);
    v[i] = NULL;

    execve(APP_PROCESS, a, v);
    fprintf(stderr, "am: %s  error: %s\n", APP_PROCESS, strerror(errno));
    for (i = 0; i < argc + NUM_ARG; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < envc + NUM_ENV; i++) {
        free(v[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

It works perfectly with ADB or SSH but even with this implementation, I get a "Segmentation fault" a the `execve()` line after an execution with `ProcessBuilder`. Why ???

**Edit3**

OK, I looked at the contents of the script init.rc which set out the environment variables. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is correctly set.

```
on init
    sysclktz 0
    loglevel 7

    mkdir /system
    mkdir /data 0771 system system
    mkdir /cache 0770 system cache
    mkdir /config 0500 root root

    # Setup the global environment
    export PATH /sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH /vendor/lib:/system/lib
    export ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 1
    export ANDROID_ROOT /system
    export ANDROID_ASSETS /system/app
    export ANDROID_DATA /data
    export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /mnt/sdcard
    export ASEC_MOUNTPOINT /mnt/asec
    export LOOP_MOUNTPOINT /mnt/obb
    export BOOTCLASSPATH /system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
```

But... for some reason they are changed or deleted depending on the context. For example, if I'm connected via ADB :

```
$ env
_=/system/xbin/env
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,32768
LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb
PS1=$(precmd)$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD:-?} $ 
USER=shell
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
ANDROID_DATA=/data
RANDOM=22124
TERM=vt100
MKSH=/system/bin/sh
HOME=/data
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
HOSTNAME=android
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
SHELL=/system/bin/sh
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

If I'm connected via SSH :

```
$ env
_=/system/xbin/env
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,32768
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
PS1=$(precmd)$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD:-?} $ 
USER=shell
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
LOGNAME=shell
ANDROID_DATA=/data
RANDOM=4546
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/system/bin/sh
MKSH=/system/bin/sh
HOME=/data/data/com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd/home
HOSTNAME=android
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
PATH=/data/data/com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd/dropbear:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/system/xbin/bb:/data/local/bin
```

If I run the command through Java :

```
$ env
_=/system/bin/printenv
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,32768
LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
ANDROID_DATA=/data
RANDOM=7424
ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=10
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

Via ADB the command `am` works very well. Via SSH it can work if I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib/`. In Java it never works :/

Comment: this looks nice http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=1BF1DCA30905444BC776098D4F81DB48?recipeId=2457

Comment: I had a similar problem, updating su binary on the mobile device solved the issue.

Comment: To simplify running processes from java, I suggest to use LibSuperUser.

Comment: Back on the problem: LD_LIBRARY_PATH has restrictions on linux, and more restrictions on Android. not that any app launched from am will likely not inherit the shell environment, because am will not spawn a process from the shell, but instead from the init. So it is very likely that you'll not be able to inherit it. I suggest to avoid this problem by putting the library in a directory already in the library search path.

Comment: Updating su doesn't solve the problem.

For LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it works now when run `am` via SSH, something that needed an `export` before. I consider that the environment variables are correctly set.

If I run `am` in the Terminal Emulator app, I get the same "Segmentation fault". My tablet runs under Android 4.0.3 with Superuser 3.0.7 and QuickSSHd 2.0.3. `am` works perfectly through SSH or ADB.

I have an other tablet, different hardware and running under Android 4.1.1 with SuperSU 1.94 and QuickSSHd 2.0.3. The `am` command and the others (`pm`, `input`) work in any circumstance on it.